# Android SDK fullscreen after startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I have Activity which shows in fullscreen mode:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawers_widget);
    setFullscreen();
}

private void setFullscreen() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

It works fine until I call external application by startActivityForResult:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

//somewhere else
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //some code
    setFullscreen(); //probably not necessery
}
```

All system controls are visible which is something I don't want. Please help.

Greathings!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity android:name="com.test.activity.SplashActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
```

Important 5th line for full screen mode.

Comment: It works fine, but what if I   1) want to use different than "Theme.Light" theme in the future?    2) want to have only one activity in fullscreen mode, not entire application?

Comment: Oops, I haven't noticed before - this method doesn't hide the bottom bar, only the top one :(

Comment: @MariuszJaskółka if you full screen specific activity put this line in acitivty tag android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen".

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a full screen just paste this code inside the oncreate function...

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 16) {
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
         getActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: It looks like getActionBar() returns null